# If $a \ne b$ in a ring $R$ satisfy $a^3 = b^3$ and $a^2b = b^2a$, show that $a^2 + b^2$ is not a unit.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $a \ne b$ in a ring $R$ satisfy $a^3 = b^3$ and $a^2b = b^2a$, show that $a^2 + b^2$ is not a unit.

So I am thinking that I should be able to do this by contradiction. So if I assume there is some element $z\in R$ such that $(a^2 + b^2)z=1$ then

$a^2z + b^2z=1$, but I'm not sure this helps in any way.

I also tried this just to see if it would reveal the right way to proceed, but I am still stuck.

$a^2 + b^2=a^2 + b^2$

$(a^2 + b^2)b=(a^2 + b^2)b$

$a^2b + b^3=a^2b + b^3$

$a^2b + b^3=b^2a + a^3$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have, $(a-b)(a^2+b^2)=a^3+ab^2-ba^2-b^3=0$

Comment: How does this show that it is not a unit? My guess is that since $a\ne b$, $(a-b)\ne 0$ so $(a^2+b^2)=0$ and so not a unit?

Comment: You cannot conclude that $a^2+b^2 = 0$ since $R$ may have zero divisors. However, you can say that if $a^2+b^2$ is a unit, then it has an inverse $u$ and thus $a-b = (a-b)(a^2+b^2)u = 0$, whence $a = b$.